# MySQL Exception Handling Prevent QThread from Stopping

Tags: python, mysql, qt, pyside2

I'm trying to prevent MySQL exception from blocking my thread and instead... giving a signal to the main thread about the reason it's being disconnected. so I tried to find a workaround on this pretty long time either with SQLAlchemy or mysql.connector none solve my problem. every time the DB loses its connection QThread would still be running after the application closed by giving me this error `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`. when the DB regains its connection, there's no problem like this (all is fine). so here's my minimal reproducible example:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import mysql.connector

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(200, 200)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("DB Status: None")
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.check_connection)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def check_connection(self):
        def callback(x):
            self.label.setText("DB Status: "+str(x))
        self.CheckConnection = CheckConnection(self)
        self.CheckConnection.result.connect(callback)
        self.CheckConnection.start()

class CheckConnection(QtCore.QThread): 
    result = QtCore.Signal(object) 
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.temp = None

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='adex_admin',user='root',password='')
            if self.connection.is_connected():
                self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
                self.cursor.execute("SELECT 1;")
                self.temp = "connected"
        except mysql.connector.Error as e:
            print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
            self.temp = "disconnected"

        self.result.emit(self.temp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

my output:

> X:\HITEK-CGI\HITEK\SIMPLE>python sqlconnector.py Warning:
> QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
> QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled
> per-screen factors.    QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen DPI.
> QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor. Error
> while connecting to MySQL 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on
> 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target
> machine actively refused it) QThread: Destroyed while thread is still
> running

this example represent exactly what i was facing in my main code. so if there's any breakthrough to this i hope my main code run as well. the point is, can i do this without producing this error `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running` while the DB loses its connection? thanks!

Comment: TYPO: change to `self.CheckConnection.result.connect(callback)`

Comment: ok i did it. but it still giving me same problem @eyllanesc

Comment: I do not reproduce the problem on Linux with PySide2 5.15.1

Comment: it only appears when you close the application while the DB is not connected

Comment: I do not have access to a DB so my connection always fails but when I close the application I do not get the message you indicate

Comment: i'm on the same version as you do. pyside 5.15.1 windows 10 python 3.8. connecting to xampp MySQL. running this code from vscode embedded terminal with this command 'python test.py' (already edited that typo you mention on my PC) without virtual-env and yes it produce same error. is there any proper video sharing media maybe like youtube to demonstrate it?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224128/discussion-between-lone-coder-and-eyllanesc).